# Draw lines in graphic representation of a tree

Tags: java, swing, data-structures, awt, binary-tree

Im trying to draw a binary tree using awt and swing. I can show the nodes of the tree but i cant draw the lines from a parent node to the child. Im using the following classes: Node(represents a node), treeGUI, DrawTree and Main.
This is the output without lines.

[image: Árvore binária]

My intent is to show lines from a parent node to the childs. I tryed use the `drawLine` metohd from `Graphics` class and this is the output:

[image: Arvore]

The method drawTree defines the position of node's values in the screen and stores in ArrayLists the node's positions. The drawLine method draw the lines. I think that the lines are like that because the values are stored in ArrayList in this specific order. I tryied various ways to draw the lines in correct way but all unsuccessful. How can i draw the lines from a parent to a child?

```
public class TreeGUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    public Node node;
    public DrawTree drawer;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public TreeGUI(Node node) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        drawer = new DrawTree(node);
        contentPane.add(drawer);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        this.node = node;
        setVisible(true);
    }

}

class DrawTree extends JPanel{

    public Node node;
    public static ArrayList listX = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList listY = new ArrayList();


    public DrawTree(Node node){
        this.node = node;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        DrawTree(g, 0, getWidth(), 0, getHeight() / node.getheight(node), node);
        listX.clear();
        listY.clear();
    }

    public void DrawTree(Graphics g, int StartWidth, int EndWidth, int StartHeight, int Level, Node node) {
        String data = String.valueOf(node.getValue());
        g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        int dataWidth = fm.stringWidth(data);

        g.drawString(data, (StartWidth + EndWidth) / 2 - dataWidth / 2, StartHeight + Level / 2);
        listX.add((StartWidth + EndWidth) / 2 - dataWidth / 2);
        listY.add(StartHeight + Level / 2);
        drawLine(g, node);

        if (node.getLeft() != null) {
            DrawTree(g, StartWidth, (StartWidth + EndWidth) / 2, StartHeight + Level, Level, node.getLeft());
        }
        if (node.getRight() != null)
            DrawTree(g, (StartWidth + EndWidth) / 2, EndWidth, StartHeight + Level, Level, node.getRight());
    }

public void drawLine(Graphics g,  Node node){
       for (int i=1; i < listY.size(); i++)
            g.drawLine((int)listX.get(i-1), (int)listY.get(i-1), (int)listX.get(i), (int)listY.get(i));
    }
```

}

método main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node raiz = null;
    raiz = raiz.insert(raiz, 35);
    raiz.insert(raiz, 25);
    raiz.insert(raiz, 75);
    raiz.insert(raiz, 30);
    raiz.insert(raiz, 20);
    raiz.insert(raiz, 12);
    raiz.insert(raiz, 6);
    raiz.insert(raiz, 23);
    raiz.insert(raiz, 90);
    TreeGUI gui = new TreeGUI(raiz);
}
```

Comment: This: `Node raiz = null;  raiz = raiz.insert(raiz, 35);` should throw a NullPointerException. Please post real functioning code.

Comment: unless insert is static, and that's not right.

Comment: Why is static not right?

Comment: 1) You're calling it on the variable, not on the class, something guaranteed to confuse anyone looking at your code. 2) Why is static in general frowned upon? It risks increasing the cyclomatic complexity of your code, increasing risk of bugs.

Comment: If you're going to call a static method of Node, at least call it on Node, not on a Node variable.

Comment: I understand, thank you, will be fixed. How can i know more about this 'cyclomatic complexity', can you recommend some material?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have the `DrawTree` function return the position it printed its text. Then have the parent draw a line from its current position to the position returned by the child's `DrawTree` function. This would allow you to get rid of the lists.

```
public Point DrawTree(Graphics g, int StartWidth, int EndWidth, int StartHeight, int Level, Node node)
{
    String data = String.valueOf(node.getValue());
    g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    int dataWidth = fm.stringWidth(data);

    // Calculate position to draw text string
    Point textPos = new Point((StartWidth + EndWidth) / 2 - dataWidth / 2, StartHeight + Level / 2);
    g.drawString(data, textPos.x, textPos.y);

    if (node.getLeft() != null) {
        Point child1 = DrawTree(g, StartWidth, (StartWidth + EndWidth) / 2, StartHeight + Level, Level, node.getLeft());
        // Draw line from this node to child node
        drawLine(g, textPos, child1);
    }
    if (node.getRight() != null) {
        Point child2 = DrawTree(g, (StartWidth + EndWidth) / 2, EndWidth, StartHeight + Level, Level, node.getRight());
        // Draw line from this node to child node
        drawLine(g, textPos, child2);
    }
    // Return position for parent to use
    return textPos;
}

public void drawLine(Graphics g, Point p1, Point p2)
{
   g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
}
```